# How are the major components arranged in the Shenzhou-11 at launch?

Tags: shenzhou

I can't exactly figure out where the first stage ends and the second stage begins and where all three components of the Shenzhou-11 space craft are located inside the fairing.

The Wikipedia image of the Shenzhou spacecraft doesn't seem to match the shape of (what I believe is) the capsule in the launchpad photos.

Is there a clear diagram of the whole thing somewhere?

I've looked at [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/spacecraft/shenzhou-spacecraft-overview/) which is very informative, but doesn't show a complete diagram.

Is the following sketch about right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**above x2:** from http://www.cctv-america.com/2016/10/14/heavenly-vessel-chinas-shenzhou-11-ready-for-liftoff

[image]

**above:** image of a Shenzhou spacecraft from [here](http://news.xinhuanet.com/english/photo/2012-06/16/131657418_51n.jpg).

[image]

**above:** Shenzhou spacecraft from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Post_S-7_Shenzhou_spacecraft.png)

Comment: The Shenzhou spacecraft is fully enclosed in a fairing, like Soyuz. The highlight reel from today's launch shows a computer model of the stack and shows the major separation events; I'm on phone so can't assemble a good answer right now.

Comment: Looking at the dimensions on Spaceflightt101, the second stage is just about the same length as one of the boosters, and the first stage nearly twice as long. There wouldn't be a significant length of interstage between second stage and payload fairing, so I think you want to move your second stage box upward in your diagram. http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/long-march-2f/

Comment: @RussellBorogove OK I see what you mean - that's not an actual "end of one thing and beginning of the next thing" point. OK this is beginning to make sense to me. Do you think the crew are sitting in the orbital, reentry, or service module (top, middle or bottom) during launch? Thank you by the way!

Comment: Reentry module, middle. The service module is full of consumables/propellant tanks and equipment and rocket engines; the orbital module is, as suggested by the name, used only in orbit. The reentry module has the parachutes and the seats, so that's where you want to be during launch. The broad-stroke design of Shenzhou is nearly identical to Soyuz, though the details differ.

Comment: @RussellBorogove your logic is inescapable.

Comment: The orbital module is the "third bedroom" for three-crew Tiangong missions (though the current mission is two-crew because they don't have consumables for 3x 30 days). I believe it also has the toilet facilities. Apollo CM essentially combines the RM/OM facilities into one module. Soyuz/Shenzhou minimizes the size of the reentry section (saving on heat shield and parachute weight) at the cost of some weight and complexity in the RM/OM interface.